# Create liquid files inside the shopify snippets directory - Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, shopify-app

I'm trying to create liquid files in my app (Rails) and upload into snippets directory of a store which installs my app. I have tried the code below

```
path = Rails.root.join("public/sample-js.liquid") 
ShopifyAPI::Asset.new(key: "snippets/sample-js.liquid", src: path)
```

I want to place the file `public/sample-js.liquid` inside `snippets`.
The above code creates a file `sample-js.liquid` inside `snippets` but the file is empty. How to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out.

```
data = File.read(path)
ShopifyAPI::Asset.create(key: "snippets/sample-js.liquid", value: data)
```